# Каково происхождение термина "вальс-каприс"? Почему так часто в хорошей литературе мы встречаем "вальс-каприз"?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, термины

Каково происхождение термина "вальс-каприс"?

Почему так часто в хорошей литературе мы встречаем "вальс-каприз"?

> Начинается программа!
>
> Два ручных гиппопотама,
>
> Разделивших первый приз,
>
> Исполняют вальс-каприз.

[Самуил Маршак: Цирк](https://elpal.livejournal.com/403100.html)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Эдвард Григ. Вальс–каприз №1 (до–диез минор), op.37.](http://www.notomania.ru/noty_kompozitsii.php?n=5504)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Victor Dandré. Анна Павлова](https://books.google.ru/books?hl=ru&id=xLIKAQAAIAAJ&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как музыкант-любитель, могу сказать, что есть хорошая, а есть профессиональная музыкальная литература (в последней пишут "каприс"); если будет "каприз" (даже если это хорошая литература), то классические музыканты, скорее всего, воспримут это как отклонение, которое имеет место быть (но, будучи людьми непрактичными и незлобными, особо обижаться не будут). Каприччо - часто закрепившееся название у конкретных произведений (Итал. каприччо Чайковского). У Паганини есть Каприс № 24: если назвать его "капризом", то это будет воспринято как неверное название (хотя классических музыкантов еще больше передергивает, когда он звучит на телефонах).

Answer (score 2):

Как сообщает Вики, "каприс" в переводе и есть "каприз". Только музыкальный.) Наверно, поэтому второй вариант тоже допустим.

Answer (score 2):

> [Каприччио, каприс](http://www.belcanto.ru/capriccio.html)
>   **Каприччио** (итал. capriccio, букв. — каприз, прихоть; множеств. число — каприччи), также **каприс** (франц. caprice).
>   Инструментальная пьеса свободной формы, в блестящем виртуозном стиле. Для множества каприччио типична причудливая смена эпизодов, настроений.

Термина *каприз* в музыке нет.

Answer (score 1):

Итальянское слово "capriccio" означает **каприз, прихоть.** В музыке оно или его производные встречаются довольно часто: так называют пьесы, свободные по построению, **капризного, изменчивого характера**. Таково, например, Итальянское каприччио Чайковского, написанное под впечатлением его поездки в Италию.

**Иногда употребляют не итальянскую, а французскую форму этого термина - каприс (caprice).** Широко известны скрипичные каприсы Паганини - виртуозные, причудливые пьесы.

http://allforchildren.ru/music/msr149.php